# How to apply UDF to collected Rows? (fails with "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Column")

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe one contains data like this

first dataframe is something like this

```
+-----+-----------+-----+----------------------+
|value|mergeValues|table|columnName            |
+-----+-----------+-----+----------------------+
|1    |1,2,3      |     |columnName1           |
|2    |4,5,6,7    |     |columnName1           |
|3    |8,9        |     |columnName1           |
|1    |1,2,3      |     |columnName4           |
|2    |4,5,6,7    |     |columnName4           |
|3    |8,9        |     |columnName4           |
|1    |1,2,3      |     |columnName5           |
|2    |4,5,6,7    |     |columnName5           |
|3    |8,9        |     |columnName5           |
|1    |1,2,3      |     |columnName6           |
+-----+-----------+-----+----------------------+
```

Another dataframe structure is shown below

```
columnName1 | columnName2 | columnName3 |columnName4 |columnName5 | columnName6 
1               
3
2
4
5
```

Now I have to create mapped dataframe like this.

```
Mapping logic is :
 get value from 2ndDF and check firstdf mergeValue if that contains then map to firstdf value.
here value of 2nd df columnName1 is 1 it is present in firstDf mergeValues list map it to firstDf[value] which is 1. same for 2,3,4,5,6,7 ...
```

```
columnName1 | columnName2 | columnName3 |columnName4 |columnName5 | columnName6 
1               
1
1
2
2
```

To do this i'm using UDF way but it is failing, what is the correct way to create this data frame.

My code is:

```
val firstDF=sparkSession.read.load(first)
val testDF = sparkSession.read.load(test)

val populateColumn: ((String, String, String) => String) = (mergeValues: String, value: String,
                                                            actualValue: String) => {
  if (mergeValues.contains(actualValue.trim)) {
    value
  } else {
    actualValue
  }

}


val populateColumnUdf = udf(populateColumn)

val firstDFList=firstDF.collect
firstDFList.foreach(Case => {
  println(Case)
  testDF.withColumn(Case.getAs("columnName"), populateColumnUdf(Case.getAs("mergeValues"),
    Case.getAs("value"), col(Case.getAs("columnName"))))
})

testDF.show
```

This is the error i'm getting

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: can you clarify the mapping from 1st data frame to the 2nd dataframe (with the column1 to column5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jacek Laskowski said, in your code, **Case** is a org.apache.spark.sql.Row type

Calling **getAs** on a **Row** returns the value of this row at a specific field  (for example, the value of the first row in the first dataframe is "1,2,3" at the "mergeValues" column)

The **withColumn** method expects the two parameters. The first parameter is the name of the column you want to replace and the second parameter is the **org.apache.spark.sql.Column** that is the replacement column.

In the second parameter, is where you provide your udf. The udf takes in columns as parameters. These input columns' datatypes should correspond to the types of the inputs that the function (in this case, **populateColumn**) that the udf wraps around expects.

Not sure what your col() function does inside the arguments you've provided to your udf in your code.

If I understand your code correctly, you'd looking for something like the following (this code is incomplete and does not run):

```
val firstDF = sparkSession.read.load(first)
val testDF = sparkSession.read.load(test)

val populateColumn: ((String, String, String) => String) =
    (mergeValues: String, value: String, actualValue: String) => {
    if (mergeValues.contains(actualValue.trim)) {
      value
    } else {
      actualValue
    }
  }

 val populateColumnUdf = udf(populateColumn)

 val replacementCol = new Column("columnName1")

//mergeValuesCol and valueCol needs to be the columns from firstDF
testDF.withColumn("columnName1", populateColumnUdf(mergeValuesCol, valueCol, replacementCol))
```

You need to provide values from the external columns (mergeValues and value) of **firstDF** (See [Passing a data frame column and external list to udf under withColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409857/passing-a-data-frame-column-and-external-list-to-udf-under-withcolumn) for a reference).

Or maybe look into merging/joining two dataframes given a condition.

Hope this helps somewhat!
Thank you to the people who edited the question so I could understand what the question was asking :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the types in the part where you do the following:

```
populateColumnUdf(Case.getAs("mergeValues"), Case.getAs("value"), col(Case.getAs("columnName")))
```

`Case` is of type `Row` and `getAs` gives you *the value of a given fieldName.* (see [org.apache.spark.sql.Row](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row)). That's definitely **not** a `Column` that your `populateColumnUdf` expects. In this context, you'd rather use `populateColumn` Scala function. You've left DataFrame/UDF context and are in Scala only.