# How to pass the parameter to User-Defined Function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a user-defined function:

```
calc = udf(calculate, FloatType())

param1 = "A"

result = df.withColumn('col1', calc(col('type'), col('pos'))).groupBy('pk').sum('events')

def calculate(type, pos):
   if param1=="A":
       a, b = [ 0.05, -0.06 ]
   else:
       a, b = [ 0.15, -0.16 ]
   return a * math.pow(type, b) * max(pos, 1)
```

I need to pass a parameter `param1` to this `udf`. How can I do it?

Comment: you may overload udf

Comment: @MaulikDoshi: Could you please show how to do it?

Comment: Can you show the syntax of udf?

Comment: @MaulikDoshi: This is `def calculate(type, pos):`. Do you mean that you'd need to see the complete function?

Comment: @Dinosaurius Yes

Comment: @pissall: Please see my update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a data frame column and external list to udf under withColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409857/passing-a-data-frame-column-and-external-list-to-udf-under-withcolumn)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `lit` or `typedLit` as a parameter for your `udf` like this:

In Python:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, lit
mult = udf(lambda value, multiplier: value * multiplier)
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1,),(2,),(3,)]).toDF()
df.select(mult(col("_1"), lit(3)))
```

In Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, col, lit}
val mult = udf((value: Double, multiplier: Double) => value * multiplier)
val df = sparkContext.parallelize((1 to 10)).toDF
df.select(mult(col("value"), lit(3)))
```

Comment: So, in my case I can use `lit(param1)`?

Comment: Yes! `lit` will just act as another column with a unique value.

Comment: Sorry I gave you an answer in Scala not in Python, but the idea is the same!

Comment: So, lit creates an additional column in `df`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your concern but it is not going to alter your original df. It will use the value of `lit` and act like it is a separate column.

Comment: Let me test it. I use PySpark, not Scala.