# Custom function over pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to apply a custom function over rows in a pyspark dataframe.
This function takes the row and 2 other vectors of the same dimension. It outputs the sum of the values of the third vector for each matching values from the row in the second vector.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Function:

```
def V_sum(row,b,c):
    return float(np.sum(c[row==b]))
```

What I want to achieve is simple with pandas:

```
pd_df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0]], columns=['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'])
   t1  t2  t3  t4
0   0   1   0   0
1   1   1   0   0
2   0   0   1   0
3   1   0   1   1
4   1   1   0   0

B = np.array([1,0,1,0])
V = np.array([5,1,2,4])

pd_df.apply(lambda x: V_sum(x, B, V), axis=1)
0    4.0
1    9.0
2    7.0
3    8.0
4    9.0
dtype: int64
```

I would like to perform the same action in pyspark.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext("local")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

spk_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0]], ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'])
spk_df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
| t1| t2| t3| t4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I thought about using udf but I can't get it to work

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

V_sum_udf = F.udf(V_sum, FloatType()) 
spk_df.select(V_sum_udf(F.array(*(F.col(x) for x in spk_df.columns))).alias("results")).show()
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong because it yields:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27726.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 90.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 90.0 (TID 91, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got non-column data that you want to use inside a function along with column data to compute a new column, a UDF + closure + withColumn as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409857/passing-a-data-frame-column-and-external-list-to-udf-under-withcolumn) is a good place to start.

```
B = [2,0,1,0] 
V = [5,1,2,4]

v_sum_udf = F.udf(lambda row: V_sum(row, B, V), FloatType())
spk_df.withColumn("results", v_sum_udf(F.array(*(F.col(x) for x in spk_df.columns))))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried running your code, it doesn't throw any error until I try to display the results with show().

Comment: Using spk_df.withColumn("results", v_sum_udf(F.array(*(F.col(x) for x in spk_df.columns)))) gives me the correct result. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.