# Can we use keyword arguments in UDF

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

Question I have is can we we use keyword arguments along with UDF in Pyspark as I did below. conv method has a keyword argument conv_type which by default is assigned to a specific type of formatter however I want to specify a different format at some places. Which is not getting through in udf because of keyword argument. Is there a different approach of using keyword argument here?

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td,date

tpid_date_dict = {'69': '%d/%m/%Y', '62': '%Y/%m/%d', '70201': '%m/%d/%y', '66': '%d.%m.%Y', '11': '%d-%m-%Y', '65': '%Y-%m-%d'}

def date_formatter_based_on_id(column, date_format):
    val = dt.strptime(str(column),'%Y-%m-%d').strftime(date_format)
    return val

def generic_date_formatter(column, date_format):
    val = dt.strptime(str(column),date_format).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return val

def conv(column, id, conv_type=date_formatter_based_on_id):
    try:
        date_format=tpid_date_dict[id]
    except KeyError as e:
        print("Key value not found!")
    val = None
    if column:
        try:
            val = conv_type(column, date_format)
        except Exception as err:
            val = column
    return val

conv_func = functions.udf(conv, StringType())

date_formatted = renamed_cols.withColumn("check_in_std", 
conv_func(functions.col("check_in"), functions.col("id"), 
generic_date_formatter))
```

So the problem is with the last statement(**date_formatted = renamed_cols.withColumn("check_in_std", 
    conv_func(functions.col("check_in"), functions.col("id"), 
    generic_date_formatter))**)
Since the third argument **generic_date_formatter** is a keyword argument.

On trying this I get following error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Comment: Maybe pass `functions.lit('%Y-%m-%d')` into your UDF as a default format string if the id lookup fails?

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe I was not clear enough.

Comment: @Hitobat understood your suggestion. Is there a way by which I can dynamically chage the method itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use `udf` with keyword arguments. `UserDefinedFunction.__call__` [is defined with positional arguments only](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a9350d7095b79c8374fb4a06fd3f1a1a67615f6f/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py#L166-L169):

```
def __call__(self, *cols):
    judf = self._judf
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    return Column(judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)))
```

but the problem you have is not really related to keyword arguments. You get exception because `generic_date_formatter` is not a `Column` object but a function.

You can create `udf` dynamically:

```
def conv(conv_type=date_formatter_based_on_id):
    def _(column, id):
        try:
            date_format=tpid_date_dict[id]
        except KeyError as e:
            print("Key value not found!")
        val = None
        if column:
            try:
                val = conv_type(column, date_format)
            except Exception as err:
                val = column
        return val
    return udf(_, StringType())
```

which can be called:

```
conv_func(generic_date_formatter)(functions.col("check_in"), functions.col("id"))
```

Check [Passing a data frame column and external list to udf under withColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37409857/9613318) for details.

Comment: Thanks this is also neat. Note: this would change the conv method signature hence have to make changes in existing code.