# Pandas_udf issue: Apply function to every row where data is ArrayType

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe where multiple columns contain arrays of different lengths. I want to iterate through the relevant columns and clip the arrays in each row so that they are the same length. In this example,  length of 3.

This is an example dataframe:

```
id_1|id_2|id_3|        timestamp     |thing1       |thing2       |thing3
A   |b  |  c |[time_0,time_1,time_2]|[1.2,1.1,2.2]|[1.3,1.5,2.6|[2.5,3.4,2.9]
A   |b  |  d |[time_0,time_1]       |[5.1,6.1, 1.4, 1.6]    |[5.5,6.2, 0.2]   |[5.7,6.3]
A   |b  |  e |[time_0,time_1]       |[0.1,0.2, 1.1]    |[0.5,0.3, 0.3]   |[0.9,0.6, 0.9, 0.4]
```

So far I have,

```
 def clip_func(x, ts_len, backfill=1500):
     template = [backfill]*ts_len
     template[-len(x):] = x
     x = template
     return x[-1 * ts_len:]

clip = udf(clip_func, ArrayType(DoubleType()))

for c in [x for x in example.columns if 'thing' in x]:
    missing_fill = 3.3
    ans = ans.withColumn(c, clip(c, 3, missing_fill))
```

But is not working. If the array is too short, I want to fill the array with the missing_fill value.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 24 of type <class 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: have you tried `clip = udf(clip_func, DoubleType())`? the example in the docs uses `IntegerType`, not `ArrayType`, so that would be my only suggestion on what looks wrong here.

Comment: Your question asks to clip the array to a given length, but based on your code it seems what you really want to do is have the `thing` arrays be the same length as the `timestamp` arrays. Is that correct?

Comment: Anyway your error is because you're passing python literals to the `udf` when you should be passing column literals (`pyspark.sql.functions.lit`)

Comment: `df = df.withColumn(c, clip(col(c),lit(3),lit(missing_fill)))` Atleast you won't get the error.

Comment: yeah append to beginning is right. I used lit and that stopped giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is cause by passing in `3` and `missing_fill` as python literals to `clip`. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241609/5858851), the inputs to the `udf` are converted to columns.

You should instead be passing in column literals.

Here is a simplified example DataFrame:

```
example.show(truncate=False)
#+---+------------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
#|id |timestamp               |thing1              |thing2         |thing3              |
#+---+------------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
#|A  |[time_0, time_1, time_2]|[1.2, 1.1, 2.2]     |[1.3, 1.5, 2.6]|[2.5, 3.4, 2.9]     |
#|B  |[time_0, time_1]        |[5.1, 6.1, 1.4, 1.6]|[5.5, 6.2, 0.2]|[5.7, 6.3]          |
#|C  |[time_0, time_1]        |[0.1, 0.2, 1.1]     |[0.5, 0.3, 0.3]|[0.9, 0.6, 0.9, 0.4]|
#+---+------------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

You just need to make one small change in the arguments passed to the `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf

def clip_func(x, ts_len, backfill):
    template = [backfill]*ts_len
    template[-len(x):] = x
    x = template
    return x[-1 * ts_len:]

clip = udf(clip_func, ArrayType(DoubleType()))

ans = example
for c in [x for x in example.columns if 'thing' in x]:
    missing_fill = 3.3
    ans = ans.withColumn(c, clip(c, lit(3), lit(missing_fill)))

ans.show(truncate=False)
#+---+------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
#|id |timestamp               |thing1         |thing2         |thing3         |
#+---+------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
#|A  |[time_0, time_1, time_2]|[1.2, 1.1, 2.2]|[1.3, 1.5, 2.6]|[2.5, 3.4, 2.9]|
#|B  |[time_0, time_1]        |[6.1, 1.4, 1.6]|[5.5, 6.2, 0.2]|[3.3, 5.7, 6.3]|
#|C  |[time_0, time_1]        |[0.1, 0.2, 1.1]|[0.5, 0.3, 0.3]|[0.6, 0.9, 0.4]|
#+---+------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

As your `udf` is currently written:

- When the array is longer than `ts_len`, it will truncate the array from the beginning (left side).
- When the array is shorter than `ts_len`, it will append the `missing_fill` at the start of the array.