# Pass a dictionary to pyspark udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am new to pyspark, and I am trying to use a udf to map some string names. I have to map some data values to new names, so I was going to send the column value from sparkdf, and dictionary of mapped fields to a udf, instead of writing a ton of `.when()`'s after `.withColumn()`.

Tried passing just 2 strings to the udf, and it works, but passing the dictionary doesn't.

```python
def stringToStr_function(checkCol, dict1) :
  for key, value in dict1.iteritems() :
    if(checkCol != None and checkCol==key): return value

stringToStr_udf = udf(stringToStr_function, StringType())

df = sparkdf.toDF().withColumn(
    "new_col",
     stringToStr_udf(
        lit("REQUEST"),
        {"REQUEST": "Requested", "CONFIRM": "Confirmed", "CANCEL": "Cancelled"}
     )
)
```

But getting this error about method col() does not exist. any ideas?:

```python
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1957, in wrapper
    return udf_obj(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1918, in __call__
    return Column(judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 60, in _to_seq
    cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 48, in _to_java_column
    jcol = _create_column_from_name(col)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 41, in _create_column_from_name
    return sc._jvm.functions.col(name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 323, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:

py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks for any help. I am using aws glue and Python 2.x, and I am testing in a notebook.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe but I can't find it at the moment. You can do `stringToStr_udf = udf(lambda col: stringToStr_function(col, {"REQUEST": "Requested", "CONFIRM": "Confirmed", "CANCEL": "Cancelled"}), StringType())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a data frame column and external list to udf under withColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409857/passing-a-data-frame-column-and-external-list-to-udf-under-withcolumn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409857/passing-a-data-frame-column-and-external-list-to-udf-under-withcolumn):

> The cleanest solution is to pass additional arguments using closure

However, you don't need a `udf` for this particular problem. (See [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297050/5858851))

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.when` to implement [`IF-THEN-ELSE` logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col, lit, when

def stringToStr_function(checkCol, dict1):
    return coalesce(
        *[when(col(checkCol) == key, lit(value)) for key, value in dict1.iteritems()]
    )

df = sparkdf.withColumn(
    "new_col",
    stringToStr_function(
        checkCol = lit("REQUEST"),
        dict1 = {"REQUEST": "Requested", "CONFIRM": "Confirmed", "CANCEL": "Cancelled"}
    )
)
```

We iterate through the items in the dictionary and use `when` to return the `value` if the value in `checkCol` matches the `key`. Wrap that in a call to `pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce()` which will return the first non-null value.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, this is better and more succinct. what i was hoping for.  was aware that udf's are slower, but wasn't sure how to do this.  thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to solve this with a UDF and a broadcasted dictionary.  pault's solution is clever and seems to rely on the auto broadcasting of the dictionary cause it's small.  Don't think pault's solution works for a dictionary that's bigger than the autobroadcast limit.  Explicitly broadcasting is the safest way to write PySpark code in my opinion.  The UDF approach can also be better if the logic cannot be expressed with the native Spark functions.

Suppose you have the following DataFrame.

```
+-------+
| status|
+-------+
|REQUEST|
|CONFIRM|
+-------+
```

Here's the code to apply the mapping dictionary to the column.

```py
def stringToStr(dict1_broadcasted):
    def f(x):
        return dict1_broadcasted.value.get(x)
    return F.udf(f)

df = spark.createDataFrame([["REQUEST",], ["CONFIRM",]]).toDF("status")
b = spark.sparkContext.broadcast({"REQUEST": "Requested", "CONFIRM": "Confirmed", "CANCEL": "Cancelled"})
df.withColumn(
    "new_col",
     stringToStr(b)(F.col("status"))
).show()
```

```
+-------+---------+
| status|  new_col|
+-------+---------+
|REQUEST|Requested|
|CONFIRM|Confirmed|
+-------+---------+
```

See [this post](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/udf-dict-broadcast/) for more details about all the errors you might encounter when broadcasting dictionaries for PySpark.  It's hard to get right, but a powerful technique to have in your toolkit.